# Are we getting a new design?

Tags: discussion, design

Is the site's design being tweaked? I just noticed that a bunch of icons and other UI elements (like the upvote/downvote/accept icons and formatting toolbar) have a new, somewhat flatter design. Some colours (like the background for favourite tags) also appear different.

Is the site's design being tweaked? I was under the impression that beta sites cannot have custom designs. Or is this being applied to all beta sites?

Comment: Just noticed that. maybe it's part of the improvement they are doing. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation?cb=1

Comment: All of the beta site themes are being updated. We're converting them all to a new LESS framework which will allow us to more easily fix bugs globally and release new features in the future.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers If you could post that as an answer, maybe with a link to an official source or something, I'd be happy to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the beta site themes are being updated. We are converting them all to a new LESS framework which in the future will allow us to more easily fix bugs globally and release new features like the [new user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features) that is being tested and developed on Meta Stack Exchange.